# bend text between ellipsoids

Tags: tikz-pgf, alignment

I want to have some text aligned to the center of the top or bottom of an ellipse. I've tried

```
\documentclass[border=0.5]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) ellipse [x radius=3, y radius = 2];
        \draw (0,0) ellipse [red,x radius=4, y radius = 2.66];
        \draw(0,0) ++(-3.5,0)  [decorate,decoration={text along path, text={This text should be between the eppelipses in the bottom half}}] arc [start angle=-160, end angle=-10, x radius=3.5, y radius = 3];
        \draw(0,0) ++(-3.5,0)  [decorate,decoration={text along path, text= {This text should be centered and in the top half}}] arc [start angle=160, end angle=10, x radius=3.5, y radius = 4];
        \node at (0,0) {center text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you need to run the arc over the full length and also account for the height of the text. **EDIT**: Added `text align=center`, another big thanks to Max!

```
\documentclass[border=0.5]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) ellipse [x radius=3, y radius = 2];
        \draw (0,0) ellipse [red,x radius=4, y radius = 2.66];
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{(3.5cm+height("T")*0.5pt)*1pt/1cm}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\myy}{(2.33cm+height("T")*0.5pt)*1pt/1cm}
        \draw [decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,
         text={This text should be between the ellipses in the bottom half}}] 
        ({-\myx},0) arc [start angle=-180, end angle=00, x radius=\myx, y radius = \myy];
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{(3.5cm-height("T")*0.5pt)*1pt/1cm}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\myy}{(2.33cm-height("T")*0.5pt)*1pt/1cm}
        \draw   [decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,
         text= {This text
        should be centered and in the top half}}] 
         (180:{\myx} and \myy) arc [start angle=180,
        end angle=0, x radius=\myx, y radius = \myy];
        \node at (0,0) {center text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I forgot to adjust the y radius, will do that in a bit.

Comment: The thing is that I want to center both to the shell, but also such that the center of the text is on the highest/lowest point on the eppelipse

Comment: @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen Sorry, need to run now. Either someone else takes over or I'll do in a few hours.

Comment: No worries ;-) I'm not in a hurry

Comment: What I ment with alignment was that horizontal alignment would be nice (This comment is because I felt the previous one was unclear)

Comment: @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen You can add  `text align=center` to the decoration options. Also see section 48.6 of the [pgf manual](http://ctan.triasinformatica.nl/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), there are _a lot_ of cool options.